# Rails. Count records that have a specific attribute:string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, count, attributes

I have a model with a string attribute. This attribute (status) is updated to `seen`, `notseen`, `hired`, and `reject` depending on certain variables within my app.

I would like to count all records where `status != reject`.

Looking at the docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count) it looks like it should be something like;

```
<%= Mymodel.count(:conditions => [ "status = ?", 'reject' ]) %>
```

but this is not correct, it returns a count of all instances regardless of status.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<%= MyModel.where.not(status: 'reject').count %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
<%= MyModel.where.not(:status =>  'reject').count %>
```

Comment: I accepted Marco Roth's answer as he posted first. Yours also works though.